# validation of file on server side

Tags: java, spring, file

I am uploading an .exe file to server as mulitipart file  and am using Tika api to detect the mime type. To detect the mime type am reading the content of file using input-stream. While reading the content of file via inputstream is there a chance the file gets executed on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Before answer your question I want to point out that you **SHOULDN'T DO THIS** because you let every one to upload an executable and that run it. What if I have bad intentions?

Now. You want to execute a file compiled I guess for a Windows platform. Is the machine that hosts your app a Windows machine? If yes you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` to run the cli command that executes the file.

Comment: I don't want to upload any of the executable files on the server. To do that am using tika-core API to detect the mime type based on content of the file. When i read the content of the file using BufferedInputStream is there a chance the file gets executed while reading the content?